# Erro e duvidas sql FireBird

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

**Eu possuo este código de tabela**

```
CREATE TABLE news (
    id_news INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    text TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_news),
    KEY slug (slug)
);
```

**Que está apresentando o seguinte erro**

> Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
>
> -Dynamic SQL Error
>
> -SQL error code = -104
>
> -Token unknow - line 7, column 18
>
> -(

Eu acredito que o problema seja na parte "KEY slug(slug)", gostaria de uma explicação do que significa esse atributo e o motivo do erro.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema com SQL no Firebird](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286885/problema-com-sql-no-firebird)

Answer (score 2):

Desconheço o uso da palavra  `KEY` isolada apenas no comando `CREATE TABLE`, `KEY` é combinada assim:

`PRIMARY KEY` - para definir a chave primária
`FOREIGN KEY` - para definir uma chave estrangeira

Como poderia ser uma *feature* exclusiva do `firebird` procurei na documentação mas realmente não existe somente a palavra reservada `KEY` em `CREATE TABLE`. Veja aqui a documentação: [CREATE TABLE firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html)

Há então um erro de sintaxe na linha `KEY slug (slug)`. Resta saber se `slug` faz relação de chave estrangeira com outra tabela, mas nesse caso a sintaxe correta seria:

```
FOREIGN KEY (slug) REFERENCES nome-da-tabela (nome-do-campo)
```

Comment: Eu estou seguindo a documentação do framework CodeIgniter e ele pede pra criar uma tabela usando esta key slug, pode conferir e me ajudar a encontrar uma outra alternativa para o que se pede?
Aqui está a pagina que estou lendo
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html

Comment: Espera ai, você marcou a tag `firebird` na pergunta, mas esse link é pra `MySQL`, chegou a ler? *Connect to your database and run the SQL command below (MySQL)*

Comment: Em `MySQL`, `KEY` como foi usado serve para criar um índice, e isso funciona só no `MySQL`, se tentar rodar em um banco de dados diferente do que está recomendando no link não vai funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Não está claro na descrição do problema o objetivo de definir como key o atributo news.slug e como esta seguindo uma documentação de um framework acredito que não tenho conhecimento do dominio do problema.

Mas a mensagem de erro está relacionado a um problema de sintaxe. Para criar uma chave candidata, ou seja um atributo que receberá um valor que não poderá se repetir, mas não é o atributo identificado(primary key), no firebird segue o seguinte modelo:

```
ALTER TABLE nometabela 
ADD CONSTRAINT nomeindice UNIQUE (nomeatributo);
```

ou

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nomeindice ON nometabela (nomeatributo);
```